# What are the requirements to add onepagescroll on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add **onepagescroll** on my website, I find it difficult to solve this problem, maybe because I am still learning stage.

Comment: Are you talking about [this plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)?

Comment: There's a simple example right there on the web page. Please post the code you tried.

Comment: yes, I have a [content file](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), but I can not install it, I want to install OnePageScroll on my Website.

Comment: thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to structure your page like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Each of those section tags represent a "page", so when you scroll it just scrolls to the next section.

You also have to add jquery, the onepagescroll plugin and a script that calls the plugin on your main element

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> //embed jquery
<script src="path/to/the/plugin/file.js"></script> //embed plugin
<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() { //wait for jquery
  $('#main').onepage_scroll(); //start the plugin
});

</script>
```

You may also check [the plugins documentation](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), which was mentioned by Barmar or follow [a tutorial to create a demo page](https://onextrapixel.com/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/).

Comment: I tried that way, the results are not as expected, do you think there is another scripting language or CSS that makes OneScrollPage not running on my website?

Comment: or maybe you have a **OneScrollPage.js** file ready to install on all website conditions?

Comment: @AdimanCipangwaren Unless you post your code there's no way for us to know what you're doing wrong.